# How to add double subscript to a symbolic variable?

Tags: maxima, subscript

How can I add a double subscript (add a subscript to the subscript) to a variable, when I try to type it in to the Maxima Computer Algebra System?

So for example, I would like to have variables named *U_{off_{U9}}*, *I_{b_{U9}}* which should look like this:[image: The above expression rendered with a LaTex engine]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be using the user interface wxMaxima, which might be trying to be helpful with subscripts. So what I say below applies to command line Maxima, which has a plain text interface, in which a "nice" UI is approximated by being clever with character placements.

Command line Maxima has no problem with nested subscripts:

```
(%i2) U['off[U9]];
(%o2)                        U
                              off
                                 U9
(%i3) I[b[U9]];
(%o3)                         I
                               b
                                U9
```

Note that I had to write `U['off[whatever]]` instead of `U[off[whatever]]`. That's because `off` is an unused, undocumented built-in variable, which has a value (equal to `false`). The presence of `off` (and corresponding `on`) is a bug; sorry about that.

Here are the same two examples, writing `U9` as `U[9]`:

```
(%i4) U['off[U[9]]];
(%o4)                        U
                              off
                                 U
                                  9
(%i5) I[b[U[9]]];
(%o5)                         I
                               b
                                U
                                 9
```

Multiple subscripts are OK too, e.g. `U[1,x,z[4]`.